# R ggplot2: using both theme() and theme_light for a graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I want to use both, `theme_light()` and `theme()` for generating a simple&nice graph but  `theme_light()` seems to override anything I want customize with `theme()`- in my case I want to customize the font (using package extrafont).  So using only either `theme_light()` or `theme()` works fine. Also tried to put the `theme()` arguments in `theme_light()` which did not worked.

Is there a possibility to use the`theme_light()` layout and `theme()` for customizing the font OR does somebody know how to build the `theme_light()` layout with `theme()` so I can omit `theme_light()`?

Code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(extrafont)

#data:
a1<-dput(step_h[c(1:100), c(14,  6)])
structure(list(hourround = c(19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 
19, 19, 1, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12), value = c(37, 9, 10, 6, 48, 
8, 63, 17, 29, 11, 6, 42, 75, 63, 92, 125, 124, 119, 124, 107, 
98, 100, 46, 23, 83, 130, 44, 106, 0, 0, 16, 87, 110, 68, 79, 
74, 51, 41, 18, 96, 69, 60, 33, 0, 0, 65, 23, 49, 0, 0, 0, 21, 
69, 53, 77, 82, 80, 37, 73, 62, 116, 65, 33, 39, 59, 102, 73, 
66, 6, 73, 89, 71, 64, 14, 19, 39, 29, 0, 32, 84, 64, 68, 16, 
0, 7, 45, 24, 0, 0, 19, 21, 13, 38, 23, 22, 16, 10, 8, 10, 11
)), row.names = c(NA, -100L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000025373b81ef0>, class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))

#graph code:
ggplot(a1, aes(x=hourround))+
  geom_bar(aes(weight = value), fill="#00BFC4")+
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Hour of day", limits = c(0, 25), breaks = seq(1, 24, by = 1))+
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Steps")+
  theme(text=element_text(family='Calibri Light', size=14)) #+theme_light()
#if I add theme_light(), font is not Calibri anymore
```

Comment: What if you reverse the order, with `+ theme_light() + theme(text = ...)`? A call to `theme(...)` updates the named entries in the current theme, whereas `theme_*()` calls tend to overwrite most if not all of them. Order matters, last one wins.

Comment: ... and just in case: You could set the base family and size of default themes using e.g. `theme_light(base_size = 14, base_family = "Calibri`Light")`

Comment: Thank you very much, both solutions worked fine! I upvoted your comments, can I somehow mark them as answer?